# The method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-adapter

making a listAdapter to list a photos taken. i am sure that everything is OK here.what could be wrong??
getting error in this line :

```
adapter.add(new Photo(bitmap , "date"));
```

The method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (int)

```
public class Photo {
        public Bitmap icon;
        public String title;
        public Photo(){
            super();
        }

        public Photo(Bitmap bitmap, String title) {
            super();
            this.icon = bitmap;
            this.title = title;
        }

    }


public class PhotoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Photo> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Photo data[] = null;

    public PhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Photo[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        PhotoHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new PhotoHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            holder.del_but = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgDel);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (PhotoHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Photo photo = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(photo.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(photo.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class PhotoHolder {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView del_but;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): Process: com.project.simplify, PID: 30045
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.project.simplify/com.project.simplify.PhotoUploadActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:425)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:179)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.project.simplify.PhotoUploadActivity.setPic(PhotoUploadActivity.java:163)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.project.simplify.PhotoUploadActivity.handleBigCameraPhoto(PhotoUploadActivity.java:205)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at com.project.simplify.PhotoUploadActivity.onActivityResult(PhotoUploadActivity.java:251)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
04-22 14:08:46.113: E/AndroidRuntime(30045):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: it have to be image captured with camera

Comment: can you provide full stack?

Comment: What is it `Bitmap`? post Photo class

Comment: whatch my update. Bitmap is that captured image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter.add` works only if the dataset is a Collection, an ArrayList for instance.

Edit. That happens because that construct that takes a Java array as parameter convert it into a List through Arrays.asList. From the documentation Arrays.asList:

> Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. The size of the
>   List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but
>   the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying
>   array.

Code from Android

```
  public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
         init(context, textViewResourceId, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
  }
```

Edit you should change from:

```
public PhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Photo[] data)
```

to

```
public PhotoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Photo> data)
```

and the rest of the code accordingly

Comment: so what should i use to add the Photo item, after photo is captured ?

Comment: instead of have Photo[] you should have ArrayList<Photo>

Comment: should i put this code into PhotoAdapter ? Doesn,t get the idea

Comment: Photo photo = data[position]; how to change this line of code ?

Comment: well it is basic java and it is not related to the original question

Comment: yes, i know. but as i changed 
'ArrayList<Photo> photo = data ;
  holder.txtTitle.setText(photo.title);
  holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(photo.icon);' i get an erors on photo.title, i cant take it anymore. can you help me with this ? im really stuck

Comment: did you changed `Photo data[] = null;` to `ArrayList<Photo>` ? Inside getView `Photo photo = data[position];` becomes Photo photo = data.get(position);`

Comment: i faced other problem.. when i take a photo first time it displays clearly on listview. but if i took second one, it does not displays. How may i handle new photo? i want to add it as a second list item. is there  any way ?

Comment: i did. no one writes anything

Answer (score 0):

As your log indicates, your error is in **PhotoUploadActivity.setPic(PhotoUploadActivity.java:163)** Whatever you are doing there is causing an empty result in your onActivityResult.I presume you are giving this empty result into your Photo.icon member.

Fix that error, so your Photo class contains an real bitmap that you can use in setImageBitmap()

Comment: adapter.add(new Photo(bitmap , "date")); this is the line of code. bitmap is not null